# enable MyBatis SQL logs in WebSphere Application Server, log4j

Tags: ibatis, mybatis

We are using mybatis 3, I am want to see the SQL logs but couldn't find how to enable it. I am using log4j in my application.
I followed this mybatis documentation - http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/logging.html , but when I run the application I get the below exception. Am I missing something,

> Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error parsing SQL
>   Mapper Configuration. Cause:
>   org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: The setting logImpl is not
>   known.  Make sure you spelled it correctly (case sensitive).

Have given this setting in mybatis configuration file under configuration

```
<settings>
 <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/>
</settings>
```

Comment: this BuilderException is gone after updating the mybatis version from 3.0.3 to 3.2.2. But where to check the logs, I am using File appender in log4j properties, but there are no logs formed in the log file that I have used for file appender.
My mybatis configuration has the setting like this
    <settings>
    <setting name="logImpl" value="LOG4J"/> 
    </settings>
And this is my log4j properties

log4j.rootLogger=TRACE, file
log4j.logger.RawMaterialSupplier=TRACE
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\loging.log
......
......

Comment: Anybody has some suggestions, I am still not able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

My situation was the same: I was using mybatis 3.1, and received same error. Is seems like `logImpl` property was added in later versions (3.2).
Experimentally I've found out, that mybatis was trying to use slf4j for logging, while I want to use log4j.

*For me* the fix was to add dependency on **slf4j-log4j** bridge library( I'm using: log4j 1.2.17, slf4j-log4j12 1.7.5). So, the workaround is not to set logger for mybatis, but to set another implementation for default logging interface (slf4j-api).

Comment: so how to add the configuration?

Comment: we had maven project, so I've just added slf4j-log4j as a dependency in my pom.xml. On build time it's placed into war which is deployed on WAS